# подскажите, пожалуйста,

Tags: члены-предложения

каким членом является "бедняжка" в "Бедняжка, он вовсе её не заслуживает". М.Ю.Лермонтов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я часто себя спрашиваю, зачем я так упорно добиваюсь любви молоденькой девочки, которую обольстить я не хочу и на которой никогда не женюсь? Из чего же я хлопочу? Из зависти к Грушницкому? ***Бедняжка, он вовсе ее не заслуживает.***

***Бедняжка*** — это обособленное приложение, отнесенное к личному местоимению ***он***. Обособляется в любой позиции.

Comment: Можно ли считать обособленную конструкцию членом предложения? Я просто не знаю, как сейчас учат, но если придерживаться классической систематики, то ваш абсолютно правильный по сути ответ можно оспорить по формальным моментам. Нет?

Comment: Согласно вузовскому учебнику, обособленный оборот является единым членом предложения, отнесенным к его предикативной основе. Но он не является присловным распространителем, то есть не  образует словосочетания с подчиняющим словом. (Не являются членами предложения вводные слова).

Comment: А можно ссылочку? Ибо формулировка более чем странная. Как тогда называется это "единый член предложения"

Comment: Ссылку не могу дать, так как книга на бумаге, в Сети ее нет (Кустова Г.И. Синтаксис современного русского языка). "Странная формулировка"  дана в моем пересказе, я имела в виду, что при разборе предложения весь оборот подчеркивается как  единый член предложения. В книге же сказано, что обособленные члены - это "ТАКИЕ ЧЛЕНЫ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ, которые выражают добавочное сообщение и присоединяются на основе полупредикативной связи". Вот это уже цитата.

Comment: эта?https://alleng.org/d/rusl/rusl629.htm не хочу качать кота в мешке.

Comment: Содержание похоже, но у меня один автор (Кустова) и год издания 2013.

Comment: Ну не важно, там есть эта мысль, спасибо. По сути мне трудно что-то сказать, подозреваю сильный методологический ляп: авторы не вводят понятие "обособленного члена" как некого члена предложения, но сразу говорят об конкретных случаях обособления, полупредикативной связи... Это странно, признаки порочного круга просматриваются. Но тут я не силен, не буду спорить, снимаю.